# How to get rid of global name is not defined error?

Tags: python, web.py

I'm creating a simple web.py service like this

```
urls = (
    '/test', 'index'
)

class index:
    def GET(self):
        user_data = web.input()
        return performstuff(user_data.color, user_data.shade)

    def performstuff(color, shade):
        return "color is " + color + " shade is: " + shade

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

When I run this and go to : http://:8080/test?color=red&shade=dark I get an error `global name 'performstuff' is not defined`

How can I resolve this? Basically I am trying to create another function in my class so it can do some business logic and then I can simply return its results in my GET method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For python objects, member functions need to be referenced with `self`, i.e.:

```
def GET(self):
    user_data = web.input()
    return self.performstuff(user_data.color, user_data.shade)
```

Comment: ah ok. What if I had a different class that had the `performstuff`  method i.e. `class doit: def performstuff(color,shade): return "something"`

Comment: You would have to instantiate the class and then call the member function, which could be strung together, i.e. `x = MyClass().performstuff(a,b)`

Answer (score 1):

`performstuff` is a method of `class index`, therefore, you have to preface it with `self`.

```
def GET(self):
    user_data = web.input()
    return self.performstuff(user_data.color, user_data.shade)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Anthony

In order to access the `performstuff` method of `class doit`, you could either create an instance of the class (`myInstance = doit(); myInstance.performstuff()`, or add `@classmethod` above the method declaration and then say `doit.performstuff()`